# SVG image rendering in Chrome 55 on windows

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, svg

Has anyone come across this issue yet?

I am getting a black block in my SVG images but only in Google Chrome 55. Even if I add a solid background colour to the svg image it somehow finds it way between the solid car and the star.

Here is the page where you can view the site: http://www.abetterstartsouthend.co.uk/workforce/

Attached screenshots from Browserstack: 
[image]

[image]

```css
.dark-bg {
  background-color: #4f5355;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 5%;
}
.page-signup {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('http://www.abetterstartsouthend.co.uk/wp-content/themes/betterstart/includes/images/dark-star-bg.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 17px;
  line-height: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-signup dark-bg center">
  <p>If you’d like to keep in touch with what’s happening at A Better Start Southend, please provide your email address below.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and add it to the question. The sample code is not enough for us to recreate the problem and we shouldn't have to debug your entire website/page to determine where the problem lies either.

Comment: Can reproduce in Chrome 55/macOS Sierra on your site. Truly bizarre - seems like an SVG rendering bug.

Comment: I've edited your post to add a snippet based on your site's HTML/CSS, where others can easily reproduce the issue.

Comment: The source of the issue might be in the horrendous SVG exported by Illustrator, try replacing the contents of your SVG with this https://jsfiddle.net/ymnzhzy2/ and let me know how it goes.

Comment: @Duopixel this worked. I think it was because the SVG file had a clipping path in it. Thank you very much! I have adjusted all SVGs on the site.